# Apache Internal redirect as query parameter

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

How do I set up an internal redirect say for example:

Source: `https://www.example.com/abc/def/ghi/xyz`

Destination: `https://www.example.com/abc.html?id=/def/ghi/xyz`

I tried the below but it isn't working:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^!(.*)\.html$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/(.*)
 RewriteRule ^/abc/(.*)$ /abc.html?id=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
 RewriteRule ^/abc/(.*)$ /abc.html?id=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It's just a cleaner way of redirect that I tried. But no, it's not working still. Thanks!

Comment: is this in `.htaccess` or `.conf` file?

Comment: Its .conf file.

Comment: Hm, I tested and it works. Did you turn `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: I have loaded a 3rd party apache module, which was causing the issue. There was no problem with the redirect. Thanks!